# Pandas : vectorize lists in column with boolean values

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a dataframe like this

```
                           group_name
techniqueID                                                   
T1566.001    [APT-C-36, APT1, APT12, APT19, APT28, APT29, A...
T1027        [APT-C-36, APT18, APT19, APT28, APT29, APT3, A...
T1053.005    [APT-C-36, APT29, APT3, APT32, APT33, APT37, A...
T1204.002    [APT-C-36, APT12, APT19, APT28, APT29, APT30, ...
T1571        [APT-C-36, APT32, APT33, DarkVishnya, FIN7, La...
...                                                        ...
T1615                                                  [Turla]
T1074                                          [Wizard Spider]
T1557.001                                      [Wizard Spider]
T1588.003                                      [Wizard Spider]
T1222.001                                      [Wizard Spider]
```

and I would like to have each value of the list contains in the dataframe as columns names and vectorize the value with boolean as in the following example :

```
                 APT-C-36  APT1  APT12  APT19  APT28  ...              
    T1566.001       1        1     0      1      0
    T1027           1        0     1      1      0
    T1053.005       0        1     0      1      0
    T1204.002       1        1     1      1      1
    T1571           0        0     0      0      1
```

Any ideas, thanks in advance.

Here is my code :

```
def convert():
    with open('APT_tech.json','r') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
    df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['techniques'])
    df = df.set_index('techniqueID')
    print(df)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    convert()
```

And an extract of json file :

```
{
    "name": "APTs",
    "versions": {
        "layer": "4.1",
        "navigator": "4.1"
    },
    "description": "All techniques used by an APT group",
    "domain": "enterprise-attack",
    "techniques": [
        {
            "techniqueID": "T1584.001",
            "group_name": [
                "APT1",
                "APT29",
                "Magic Hound",
                "Transparent Tribe",
                "UNC2452"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```